# Try to fill ArrayList from object with String and int.Is not working

Tags: java, arraylist

I have class Book with three fields - name, author and isbn
I`m trying to insert the fields in ArrayList and to print:

```
book1, author1, isbn  
book2, author2, isbn2  
and... to 10
```

code:

```
public class InsertBooks {

    private static ArrayList<String> booksNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<String> booksAuthors = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Integer> booksIsbn = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    // adding books in ArrayList booksNames
    private static void addBooksNames() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            booksNames.add("Book" + i);
        }
    }
    // adding author in ArrayList booksAuthors
    private static void addBooksAuthor() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            booksAuthors.add("Author" + i);
        }
    }
    // adding author in ArrayList booksAuthors
    private static void addBooksIsbn() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            booksIsbn.add(Integer.valueOf("isbn" + i));
        }
    }

    public static void fillArrayListOfBooks() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            books.add(new Book((addBooksNames(), addBooksAuthor(), addBooksIsbn()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question: What's the reason to have separate collections for Names, Authors and ISBNs, when there is also a Book collection?

Comment: They are separate, because are separate cells from table in xampp(mySQL) and I want to fill it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to call all your `add*` functions first. Then in the loop of `fillArrayListOfBooks()` use those values.

```
void fillArrayListOfBooks()
{
    addBooksNames();
    addBooksAuthor();
    addBooksIsbn();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dbooks.add(new Book(booksNames.get(i), booksAuthors.get(i), booksIsbn.get(i)));
    }
}
```

You could easily get rid of those lists (unless you need them later):

```
void fillArrayListOfBooks()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dbooks.add(new Book("Book" + i, "Author" + i, "isbn" + i));
    }
}
```

Comment: the ArrayList it`s still empty

Comment: @PetkoPenchovski There is a typo: `dbooks.add...` should be `books.add....`. Other than that, it should work: https://ideone.com/1AUGRo